Какой корень у слова "известный"? Словообразовательная загадка
Нашла в словаре такой разбор:
Изве́стн/ый. Морфемно-орфографический словарь Тихонова.
А как можно объяснить этот вариант: почему не выделяется приставка ИЗ и суффикс Н?
А это разбор другого слова для сравнения: из/ве́ст/и/е [й/э] в том же словаре.
Вот такие повороты словообразовательной мысли)

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Моя версия ответа:

Для слова весть составлена словообразовательная цепочка: весть — из/вест/и/ть — из/вест/и/е [й/э].

При образовании глагола известить использован формант ИЗ...И. Существительное известие по семантике соответствует глаголу, чего нельзя сказать о прилагательном известный.

Образовать слово известный непосредственно от существительного весть нельзя, так как нет форманта ИЗ...Н. Соответственно, известный считается непроизводным словом в словаре Тихонова, то есть не делится на морфемы.

В  то же время в словаре Потиха словообразовательные связи не учитываются, и там есть деление на морфемы.


Два решения соответствуют разным принципам морфемного анализа.
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
ВЕСТЬ, -и; мн. род. -ей; ж. Известие, сообщение. 
Радостная, недобрая в.

ИЗВЕСТИТЬ,  св. кого о чём или с союзом что. Сообщить о чём- 
л., довести до сведения кого-л.; уведомить. И. о дне 
заседания. Он никого не известил о своём приезде. 

ИЗВЕСТИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Сообщение, сведение о ком- чём-л.; 
весть. От него давно не получали известий. Получить и. 

ИЗВЕСТНЫЙ,  1. (кому). Такой, о котором или которого знают; 
знакомый.  2. Пользующийся известностью, всеобщим 
признанием; знаменитый, прославленный. И. художник, 
писатель, поэт, актёр. 3. Определённый, установленный. 
Работать за и-ое вознаграждение. 

